# to pass the value from codebehind to hidden field textbox

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i get the regular expressions and stored in  hidRegExp.Value.Now i have to pass this value to the hidden field textbox.Pls help me to do this.
codebehind:

```
public List<string> ListOfRegularExpression { get; set; } 
string strRegularExp = string.Empty;

if (ListOfRegularExpression != null)
{
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < ListOfRegularExpression.Count; iRow++)
    {
        strRegularExp += ListOfRegularExpression[iRow].ToString() + "~~";
        if (iRow == ListOfRegularExpression.Count - 1)
        {
            strRegularExp = strRegularExp.TrimEnd("~~".ToCharArray());
            txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.ToString() + "');");
        }
     }
}

hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;
```

code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidRegExp" runat="server"  />
```

Comment: What is hidden field textbox?

Comment: sorry It is a hidden field

Comment: "hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;" This should work, what is the error you are getting.

Comment: i got no value in hidden field i have to pass the value to hidden field

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the asp hidden field tag?
Example:

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField"
              value="" 
              runat="server"/>
```

Ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i tried but value from code behind is not passing to hidden text

Comment: what value are you getting? And how are you checking its value?

Comment: How are you checking it?

Comment: i am checking by this i get the value here and to pass to hidden field lbl.Text = "The value of the HiddenField control is " + hidRegExp.Value + ".";